# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in xcode9.2

Tags: swift, core-plot, xcode9.2

After installation of cocoapods it's shows always like this likner command with existing code.i deleted derived data and clean project.can any one help me?. i am using swift 3.2 .

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'DemoApp' do


# Pods for DemoApp

pod 'CorePlot'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xcode 9, you need to use the `release-2.3` branch of Core Plot.

```
pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.3'
```